# Developing debugger in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on developing an extension (debugger) for a Javascript library. Initial results are fine and I have come across one bug (not sure if its a bug). Problem is "When a code is running multiple tabs open (for each, dev-tools is also open) and The dev-tools receive messages from all the open tabs, which should not be the case. How to prevent it from happening? any suggestions would be great help. Let me know if I need to put code related to any other files.

//Part of Manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "debugger",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "some",
"author": "some",
"devtools_page": "devtools.html",
"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "background.js"
    ]
},
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "<all_urls>"
]
}
```

// content-script.js

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage(message, function (message) {
      console.log("message sent");
});
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg.action == 'debug') {
        console.log("Message: " + msg.content);
    }
});
```

// Background.js

```
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
    var extensionListener = function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (message.destination == "panel") {
            port.postMessage(message);
            // chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id, message, sendResponse);
        }
});
```

// panel.js

```
var port = chrome.extension.connect({
    name: "my-extension"
});

port.onMessage.addListener(function (message) { 
   // do something with message
});
```

Comment: Can you show the code you use for messaging?

Comment: In your code, filter the messages based on the [`sender`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#type-MessageSender).

Comment: @Makyen could you please give me an example for the same?

Answer (score 0):

In your case object `sender` from the background message listener contains property `tab` (with tab.id), so you can recognise which tab sent this message.

Then you can get current tab using:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(foundTabs){
  //foundTabs[0].id //current tab id
});
```

And that means you can filter messages from the current tab only.